# How do I create or modify a custom filter?

Tags: 7, input-formats

I'm following [the docs here](https://www.drupal.org/node/210553) to create a custom filter.

The first sentence says:

> Go to Custom Filters (/admin/settings/customfilter) (6.x & 7.x)

However, that link just redirects me to the overall admin menu page (looks the same as if I go to /admin). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install the Custom Filters module? (https://www.drupal.org/project/customfilter)

Works fine for me after I install the module.

Answer (score 0):

The correct path for Drupal 7 (there isn't any difference between version 7.x-1 or 7.x-2 of the module) is admin/config/content/customfilter; that is what the module uses as path for its setting pages, in `hook_menu()`.

```
  $access = array('administer customfilter');
  $items = array();

  $items['admin/config/content/customfilter'] = array(
    'title' => 'Custom filters',
    'description' => 'Allow the users to define custom filters.',
    'page callback' => 'customfilter_settings',
    'access arguments' => $access,
  );

  $items['admin/config/content/customfilter/list'] = array(
    'title' => 'Filters',
    'access arguments' => $access,
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => -1,
  );

  $items['admin/config/content/customfilter/add'] = array(
    'title' => 'Add filter',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('customfilter_filter_add'),
    'access arguments' => $access,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  );
```